# How to set Chart control width into percentage

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net chart control, how do we set chart width into percentage, below scenario is chart width needs to be set with the panel width. As the chart takes only pixel. Help on this.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width:50%;border:1px solid black;"> 
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" Width="100%">
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" >
<Titles><asp:Title Text="ChartSample1"></asp:Title></Titles>
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
</asp:Panel>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;border:1px solid black;"> 
<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" Width="100%">
<asp:Chart ID="Chart3" runat="server">
<Titles><asp:Title Text="ChartSample2"></asp:Title></Titles>
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
</asp:Panel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

code behind:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 2);
Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 1);
Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 2);
Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 1);
Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 2);

Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 10);
Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 20);
Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 10);
Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 20);
Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 10);
Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 20);
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you do `<asp:Chart ID="Chart3" runat="server" style="width:100%">` and dispense with the panel? (Or, better still, dispense with using tables for layout - it's the 21st century - and use floating panels instead to put things side by side)

Comment: Thanks, but when add style="width:100%", then the chart width is stretched (because, here chart is an image).

Comment: you said "the chart width should be set to the panel width". The panel width is 100%. So if you set the chart to 100%, the same as the panel, it will inevitably stretch. What else would happen? But that _is_ what you asked for :-)

Comment: I need the chart should not be stretched, how can I achieve this. pls help

Comment: well what do you want then? If you expand it to the full width, it will be stretched. If you don't, it won't be stretched but there will be a gap. Do you want it centered in the div?

Comment: this post also has a lot of advice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721854/setting-a-dynamic-size-for-an-aspchart-control

Comment: I want a chart that to be displayed full width of the panel(any div) without stretch. The reference link may useful in my scenario, I will try it.

Comment: If you change the width of an image, like your chart, from its natural width then it stretches (unless you change the height _in direct proportion_ as well). That's just maths, there's not really a lot you can do about it. That link might be useful in terms of using the updatepanels - that way, you can get .NET to re-generate the image - it will hopefully understand the width of the area it's going to be inserted into and make the original image a different width, which would solve the problem. Hope you can make it work to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found a solution, you may try getting the `width` and `height` properties of the `panel` in codebehind.
I preferred using `panels` in the website instead of `table`.

```
double heightTable = panel1.height.value;

chart2.height = new unit(heighttable);
```